# Cant get commerce js/ stripe to authorise test transaction

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, commerce.js

I cant get commerce.js to process transaction in the ecommerce website tutorial im following. Whenever i attempt a transaction it says

```
{
  "status_code": 402,
  "error": {
    "message": "The specified payment method requires further verification",
    "type": "requires_verification",
    "param": "pi_3KuHUGSCnOzTd5gv1y7qWTUS_secret_UPSucrdQSjwfWzMRksWZkN3Sv"
  },
  "help": {
    "slack": "http://slack.commercejs.com",
    "_comment": "*help* & *console* error responses will not be returned when using production/live API keys."
  }
}
```

in the commerce js logs, but im using test keys and the card 4242424242....
[Log from Commercejs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gawzC.png)

Comment: The _comment from commerce js could be misleading, and while you are actually created a test mode PaymentIntent within Stripe, commerce js could have been referred to a different (their own?) production/live key

Comment: I fixed it , it stripe or commerce js now requires 3d auth handling I guess? The moment I implemented it, it started working